# Selecting records that have a prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

I am new to SQL Server and need help writing a query

I have been given about 400 id numbers that look like (123456, 1234555, 342345 etc). I am supposed to select all the records from a table that has those ids. The problem is the column that references these id (ActionIDreference) has a prefix (A) in front some of its values (A123456,A1234555,A342345). sometimes it (ActionIDreference) doesn't have the 'A'. I need to account for any variation in that column that references those specific ids.

I want to be able to pull up those 400 ids from the column whether it has the A in front or if there is no A, then without it.

The Table name is ActionReport.

I am using Sql Server

Hope the question is clear.

Thank you for the help

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` function to first get rid of 'A' from all the IDs then just compare with the list of IDs with `in`.

```
 select * fromActionReport
 where replace(ActionIDreference,'A','')in (123456, 1234555, 342345 )
```

Another approach could be using `union all` and `stuff()`

```
 select * fromActionReport
 where ActionIDreference like 'A%' and STUFF(ActionIDreference,1,1,'') in (123456, 1234555, 342345 )

 union all

 select * fromActionReport
 where ActionIDreference not like 'A%' ActionIDreference in (123456, 1234555, 342345 )
```

Create a table to hold ActionIDreference values you want to search. Then insert the 400 IDs into it.

```
create table search_criterion (ActionIDreference varchar(20));
insert into search_criterion values('123456'), ('1234555'), ('342345'), ('123456');
```

Now you don't know which values have 'A' as prefix in your table so you will copy all the rows and will reinsert into the table with prefix 'A'.

```
insert into search_criterion select 'A'+ActionIDreference from search_criterion;
```

Now your actual query will be:

```
 select * fromActionReport
 where ActionIDreference in (select ActionIDreference from search_criterion  );
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It is taking a lot of time to run this query, currently going over 15 minutes and still executing

Comment: Update: Threw a 'System.OutOfMemoryException' error

Comment: How many rows are there in the table? which approach you tried?

Comment: there are about a million records in the table. I tried both approaches.

Comment: I have just tested a table with almost 100 million rows and it's taking almost three minutes. I am revising my answer which will be much faster but demands some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `in` and cover all the possibilities:

```
where ActionIDreference in ('123456', '1234555', '342345', '123456', 'A1234555', 'A342345')
```

Any other approach is likely to result in a suboptimal query plan.  Yes, SQL Server can handle 800 values in an `IN` list -- and producing 800 values shouldn't be much harder than producing 400.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Create a temporary table to hold your id values

```
Create table #temp (Id varchar(10) not null primary key) /* data type should match the target table*/
```

Insert your list of values

```
Insert into #temp values ('123456'),('345678'),...
```

update your table and prefix with 'A'

```
update #temp set Id='A' + Id
```

Now repeat your first insert so your table ends up with your list of values both with and without the 'A' prefix.

Now run your query joining with the temp table

```
select a.*
from #temp t
join fromActionReport a on a.ActionIDreference=t.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load table variable with id values and id values with `A` prefix.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(id varchar(10))

-- insert without prefix
insert into @table
SELECT cast(id as varchar(10)) as id FROM (VALUES ('12345'),('13345')) as t(id)
-- insert with prefix
insert into @table
SELECT cast(CONCAT('A',id) as varchar(10)) FROM  @table
```

Now, you can apply IN condition in the master table for the ids from the table variable

```sql
SELECT * FROM ActionReport where ActionReportIDReference IN
(
Select id from @table)
```